# Windows 7 multitouch zooming?

Tags: windows-7, zoom

Are their registry changes or other applications that let me take control of pinch to zoom behavior on Windows 7 on a multi-touch tablet?

Currently, pinch to zoom appears to behave exactly like holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and scrolling the mouse wheel. Instead, I would like to use Windows Magnifier as if I were pressing <kbd>Win</kbd> and <kbd>+</kbd> or <kbd>-</kbd>. I can't find anything using Google and the Control Panel only allows me to toggle if it should listen for pinch to zoom controls at all (and not how to respond to this input).

Anybody know of any tweaks or 3rd party apps?